# Multiple hosts for the same DDNS provider

Tags: tomato

Is it possible to update multiple hosts for the same ddns provider in Tomato?  For example, lets say I have 3 hosts registered at DynDns:

```
one.dyndns.org
two.dyndns.org
three.dyndns.org
```

How do I update all three?  With dd-wrt, this was possible by using the -a switch:

```
one.dyndns.org -a two.dyndns.org -a three.dyndns.org
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to comma separate the hosts:
one.dyndns.org,two.dyndns.org,three.dyndns.org

I posted the same question to the DynDns forums and got an answer